# Python не видит файл в папке и отказывается с ним работать

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, ос

Решил написать программу для переименования массива файлов, отличающихся грубо говоря номером файла. Для тестов решил пока работать только с одним экземпляром. Вот код программы:

```
import os

in_downloads = input('Файл находится в папке "downloads"?\n')

if in_downloads.lower() == "да":
    directory = 'C:/Users/Артемий.Дмитрий-ПК/Downloads'
else:
    directory = input('Ведите путь до папки, в которой находится файл (не забудьте заменить "\\" на "/") \n')  # directory = 'D:/JoJo/манга'

name = 'Bleach - Digital Colored Comics Том 23 Глава 201 [mangalib.me].zip' #input('Введите название архива с мангой: \n')
new_name = 'блич глава 201' # имя на переименовку

spisok = str(os.listdir(directory))
print(spisok) #вывод всего содержимого в папке

ind = spisok.find(name) #нахождение индекса нужного элемента
print("Искомый объект расположен под номером ", ind) #вывод этого индекса

count = spisok.count(name)

if name in spisok:
    print('Файл находится в папке ', directory)
    os.rename(name, new_name)
    print("Файл успешно переименован!")
else:
    print('Объекты с таким именем не найдены :(')
```

На этапе переимнования файла выдает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/JoJo/goose/ballance/files_to_edit/manga_renamer.py", line 26, in <module>
    os.rename(name, new_name)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл: 'Bleach - Digital Colored Comics Том 23 Глава 201 [mangalib.me].zip' -> 'блич глава 201'
```

Для того, чтобы убедиться, что проблемма не в самом файле, сделал несколько проверок на его наличие. После чего полное выполнение программы в терминале PyCharm'а выглядит так:

```
Файл находится в папке "downloads"?
нет
Ведите путь до папки, в которой находится файл (не забудьте заменить "\" на "/") 
D:/JoJo/манга
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/JoJo/goose/ballance/files_to_edit/manga_renamer.py", line 26, in <module>
    os.rename(name, new_name)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл: 'Bleach - Digital Colored Comics Том 23 Глава 201 [mangalib.me].zip' -> 'блич глава 201'
['Bleach - Digital Colored Comics Том 23 Глава 201 [mangalib.me].zip', 'text_doc.txt', 'Новая папка']
Искомый объект расположен под номером  2
Файл находится в папке  D:/JoJo/манга
```

При попытке запустить файл даблкликом по нему, то программа после ввода пути до файла просто закрывается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка здесь:

```
os.rename(name, new_name)
```

В переменной `name` у вас только имя файла, **а не путь к нему**. Значит, файл ищется в актуальной папке, но там он не находится.

Или примените полный путь к файлам `name` и `new_name`, или измените перед этой командой актуальную папку командой

```
os.chdir('C:/Users/Артемий.Дмитрий-ПК/Downloads')
```

Answer (score 2):

Кажется что здесь не нужен `str()`, просто:

```
spisok = os.listdir(directory)
```

Плюс при переименовании не учтена папка:

```
os.rename(os.path.join(directory, name), os.path.join(directory, new_name))
```